# AuthenticationSuccessHandler failed

Tags: security, symfony, service, handler

I want to call an AuthenticationSuccessHandler if a User logs in.
But if I try it with the correct password an error occures:

> request.INFO: Matched route "login_check" (parameters: "_controller": "AppBundle\Controller\SecurityController::loginCheckAction", "_route": "login_check") [] []
>   request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 4 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/jail/home/users/requiem/rpg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php on line 96 and defined" at /home/jail/home/users/requiem/rpg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/UsernamePasswordToken.php line 36 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException(code: 0): Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 4 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/jail/home/users/requiem/rpg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php on line 96 and defined at /home/jail/home/users/requiem/rpg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/UsernamePasswordToken.php:36)"} []
>   security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []

My Files:

**security.yml**

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /rpg/main
            username_parameter: _username
            password_parameter: _password
            success_handler: security.authentication.success_handler
```

**services.yml**

```
security.authentication.success_handler:
        class: AppBundle\Handler\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
        arguments: [@security.http_utils, @service_container, {}]
        tags:
            - { name: 'monolog.logger', channel: 'security'}
```

**src/AppBundle/Handler/AuthenticationSuccessHandler**

```
namespace AppBundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;

class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler{
protected $container;

public function __construct(HttpUtils $httpUtils, ContainerInterface $cont, array $options)
{
    parent::__construct($httpUtils, $options);
    $this->container=$cont;
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request, \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface $token)
{
    $user=$token->getUser();
    $user->setLogged(new \DateTime());

    $em=$this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($request, $this->determineTargetUrl($request));
}
}
```

Comment: And when you comment out the handler? Does it work then?

Comment: Have you defined [role_hierarchy](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles) in _security.yml_?

Comment: I found the solution for my problem. The problem was, that my getter for the role hierarchy gave me a string back instead of an array.Thank you for your efforts guys.